# What determines whether computer players will ally with you in sword of the stars?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars

In sword of the stars, computer players constantly offer to make and break alliances with me, and I can't figure out if it's random or something that I'm doing. What actions cause computer players to make or break alliances with the player?